# Querying in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

How can I get the first name and last name from the table User through table Friend which is referenced by the user_id with the condition of user_id 5 and status is pending and place it in a each loop but i also need the contents of friend controller in rails. Thank a lot for the help

Controller

```
@add = Friend.where(user_id: 5, status: 'Pending')
```

User Database

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name      | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name       | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email           | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_number  | varchar      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| birth_date      | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

Friend

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| request_date | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| reason       | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| userid       | int          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
@add = Friend.joins(:user).select("users.first_name, users.last_name").where(user_id: 5, status: 'Pending')
```

Comment: Now iam joining 3 tables @add = Friend.joins(user: :profile).where(user_id: 5, status: 'Pending') but when i use it in the each loop   <td><%= s.first_name %></td> undefined method `first_name'

Comment: could you check `s` is the object of which model?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do in `Friend model`  `belongs_to user`  and then

```
@add  =Friend.where("user_id = ? AND status = ?", 5,"Pending")
```

and

```
<@add.each do |s|>
  <%s.user.first_name%>
  <%=<%s.user.last_name%>
  // and so on..
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like youre already fetching the id of the user, stored in the user_id field. In order to get the associated user, i would do

@user = User.find(@add.id)

This retrieves the user based on the id you pass, and from there you can do stuff like

@user.first_name

to get the values

Comment: How can i place it in the each loop i also need the contents of <% @add.each do |s| %>

Comment: I would do the looping beforehand, in your controller/wherever youre looking this data up, and merge the fields in. So you could do something like: @add.map {|a| u = User.find(a.id); a[:first_name] = u.first_name; a [:last_name] =u.last_name; return a}